# NIntegrate using Boole doesn't work

Tags: numerical-integration, boolean-computation

This doesn't want to work for me - I don't know why not. It usually gives me `0`, but sometimes also a different number. I know it should be a small, non-zero number.

```
myO[e1_, e2_] := (e1)/((e1) + (e2));
myU[e1_, e2_] := (1 - e2)/((1 - e1) + (1 - e2));
myV[p_, e1_, e2_] := p (e1)/(p (e1) + (1 - p) (1 - e2));
myW[p_, e1_, e2_] := p (1 - e1)/(p (1 - e1) + (1 - p) e2);

NIntegrate[ Boole[0 < e1 < e2 < 1/2 && 0 < e3 < 1/2 && e1 < p < 1 - e1 && 
                  e3 < myV[p, e1, e2] < 1 - e3 < myW[p, e1, e2] && 
                  myO[e1, e2] < e3 < myU[e1, e2]], 
                 {p, 0, 1}, {e1, 0, 1/2}, {e2, 0, 1/2}, {e3, 0, 1/2}]
```

Comment: Do you mean that sometimes the same command gives different outputs with everything else the same ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But more importantly, it doesn't give the correct value. It mostly gives zero, which cannot be true.

Comment: In version 9 I get the same result every time.  If I change the method to MonteCarlo, I get a slightly different number every time, as expected.  Raising MaxPoints makes it converge to the same result the default method gives: `0.00177529`.  In version 8 I get the same.  What version are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) or [`CylindricalDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html) to break down the inequalities into forms that can be used as limits of integration.
(Note: One might try [`BooleanMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BooleanMinimize.html) instead of `distr` below to distribute `And` over `Or`, but it changes the order of the inequalities.  Consequently, the intervals of integration end up out of order and `NIntegrate` does not work.  One could sort them, but I opted for writing `distr`, which distributes from the bottom up.)

```
 (* distribute And over Or *)
distr[e_And] := Distribute[distr /@ e, Or];
distr[e_Or] := distr /@ e;
distr[e_] := e;
 (* convert ineqs to limits of integration *)
sub = {(Less | LessEqual)[a_, b_, c_] :> {b, a, c}, 
   HoldPattern[Inequality[a_, _, b_, _, c_]] :> {b, a, c}};

simp = Reduce[
    0 < e1 < e2 < 1/2 && 0 < e3 < 1/2 && e1 < p < 1 - e1 && 
      e3 < myV[p, e1, e2] < 1 - e3 < myW[p, e1, e2] && 
      myO[e1, e2] < e3 < myU[e1, e2],
    {e1, e2, e3, p}];
NIntegrate[1, ##] & @@@ (distr[simp] /. sub /. {And | Or -> List}) // Total

(* 0.00177529 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great.

Answer (score 1):

One way to proceed is to try out portions and see where the problem lies. For instance:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[0 < e1 < e2 < 1/2 && 0 < e3 < 1/2 && e1 < p < 1 - e1], 
     {p, 0, 1}, {e1, 0, 1/2}, {e2, 0, 1/2}, {e3, 0, 1/2}]
0.0416667
```

is fine. But the inequalities

```
NIntegrate[Boole[e3 < myV[p, e1, e2] < 1 - e3 < myW[p, e1, e2]], 
     {p, 0, 1}, {e1, 0, 1/2}, {e2, 0, 1/2}, {e3, 0, 1/2}]
0.0239936 - 3.06317*10^-29 I
```

are giving (small) complex values. Most likely, this is because there are points where your function is trying to divide by zero. One culprit is the function `myW`, which, at 0,0,0 gives

```
myW[0, 0, 0]
Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0 encountered."
```